# Bison pseudo-variables returns wrong value

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have strange problem with Bison. I'm begginer, so correct me if I'm wrong, but $1,$2...and so on should return values from first, second and so on terminal/nonterminals, yes?

```
command: IDENT{printf("%s",$1);} SET{printf("%s",$1);} expression{printf("%s",$1);} ENDCMD
```

I doing compilator, and i traped because from above example, I had for expression like "a := 1" (where ident is "a", set is ":=" and num is "1") "a" in first call, "a :=" in second and "a := 1" in third.

```
%union {
    int ival;
    char *sval;
}
```

ident is sval.

Important thing, I think, is that i recently add string to my bison file. Previously everything was ok.

Comment: Ok. Now I should blame myself. I dig deeper in stackoverflow and found that: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Strings-are-Destroyed.html. Whats of course a answer.

Comment: Be careful when tagging.  Flex is for the Adobe/Apache UI framework.  Flex-lexer is used for the lexical analyzer.  Since it sounds like you found your answer; you should answer your own question.

Comment: Yeah, but i couldn't, since i have less than 10 rep and 8hours didnt pass. If you can response, I will be grateful. And about tagging, i will remember for future.

Comment: You found the answer; you should get the credit for it.  Just be sure to come back later and formally answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Now I should blame myself. I dig deeper in stackoverflow and found that: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Strings-are-Destroyed.html. Whats of course a